# Can't see attached images

Tags: support, images, 403-forbidden

Recently I can not see images attached by users in my browser. Opening an image in a new page I will see the following message:

> 403 Forbidden cloudflare-nginx

Example of a URL:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/978fH.jpg

Comment: CloudFlare is the Content Delivery provider for Imgur. It looks like the CloudFlare instance closest to you has a stale cache and didn't re-fetch images it couldn't find previously. Try what Undo suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely fallout from [Tuesday's S3 outage](https://aws.amazon.com/message/41926/), which also affected Imgur. You might try clearing your browser/DNS cache; the link you posted works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, I cleaned my browser cache, no success.